# Different OPENROWSET using EXEC or Direct call

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2022 CU3 and Target is SQL Server 2017 CU14.
I stuck in the OPENROWSET.

I check openrowset query success on SQL Server 2022 when i direct call.
like this.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','10.10.10.10,1433';'TestUser';'TestUser@@', 'SELECT @@VERSION')

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU14) (KB4484710) - 14.0.3076.1 (X64)   Mar 12 2019 19:29:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

But i have to replace ip, port into variable.
So I changed it  Declare / Set / Exec.
But SQL Server return 7202 error.

How should I fix about this.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET  @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'','''+@ip+','+@port+''';''TestUser'';''TestUser@@'', ''SELECT @@VERSION'')'

EXEC @sql
go

메시지 7202, 수준 11, 상태 2, 줄 7
sys.servers에서 서버 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
                                             '10'을(를) 찾을 수 없습니다. 올바른 서버 이름이 지정되었는지 확인하십시오. 필요하면 저장 프로시저 sp_addlinkedserver를 실행하여 sys.servers에 서버를 추가하십시오.
```

Even though I don't use variable but the result same.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',
                                             ''10.10.10.10,1433'';''TestUser'';''TestUser@@'',
                                             ''SELECT @@VERSION'')'
print(@sql)
EXEC @sql
go

메시지 7202, 수준 11, 상태 2, 줄 7
sys.servers에서 서버 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
                                             '10'을(를) 찾을 수 없습니다. 올바른 서버 이름이 지정되었는지 확인하십시오. 필요하면 저장 프로시저 sp_addlinkedserver를 실행하여 sys.servers에 서버를 추가하십시오.
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a linked server?

Comment: Linked Server compile on local server.
So if i want to use variable of target like @@servername it will be complex to make query.

Comment: The last query, without variables, is missing the single quotes for datasourse,user,password (before and after the semicolon ;) `set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'', ''10.10.10.10,1433'';''TestUser'';''TestUser@@'',''SELECT @@VERSION'')'`

Comment: @lptr or sorry.  When I test the quote was exist. but i didn't write this post. I edited now

Comment: Exec @sql should be in parentheses `EXEC (@sql)`

Comment: @lptr OMG. What a nice answer.  Yeah. I success with parentheses.   I'm really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF and double quotes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).